Sonata Admin assets webpack
I have
  "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "^4.27.1",
        "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "*",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "^4.10",
        "sonata-project/media-bundle": "^4.11.1",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "^5.6",
       "symfony/webpack-encore-bundle": "^1.16",
   "symfony/asset": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "6.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^2",
        "symfony/form": "6.4.*",

own webpack and packages json.
How i can get / include sonata admin webpack for adding own scripts (when i load my scripts as second i have two boostrap in one page.
I see in repo : https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle assets but is not installed to my assets.

I should remove compiled sontata admin and add for my compilation ? There is some tutorial how to do this ?
UPDATE 1
I add to my app.js
import 'sonata-admin/js/app'

to packages.json
"sonata-admin": "file:./vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/assets",
webpack is compiling
DONE  Compiled successfully in 531ms
sonata_Admin
assets:
    remove_javascripts:
        - 'bundles/sonataadmin/app.js'

but front not working correctly
what I miss ?
